# Почему в python не реализовано индексация пустого списка?

Tags: python, list

Вот код. Я хочу просто перевернуть массив...

```
x = [10,1,5,2,4,8,6,7,3,9]
print (x, "\n")

temp = [i for i in range (len(x))]

i = 0
end = len(x) - 1
while (end >= 0):
    temp[i] = x[end]
    i += 1
    end -= 1

k = 0
start = 0
while (k < len(temp)):
    x[start] = temp[k]
    k += 1
    start += 1

del(temp)
print (x)
```

Чтобы перевернуть массив создаю временную переменную temp, изначально хотел вот так:

```
temp = []
# И потом заполнить сходу в цикле путем типо:
temp[i] = x[k]
x[j] = temp[p]
```

Но увы, python не разрешает индексировать пустой массив вообще вне цикла внутри цикла...
Приходится заполнять временный массив с размером того массива которого хочу перевернуть...
Почему так нельзя ? Не пойму что плохого в этом чтобы не добавили такую возможность... Или я не знаю как это сделать... Как можно это решить если можно решить... ?

Версия Python3.11.6

Comment: А просто использовать встроенный метод `.reverse()` вам почему-то нельзя?

Comment: Замените список на словарь. Всё заработает.

Comment: Или `temp = [None] * len(x)`.

Comment: @andreymal Нуу, по коду же видно что пытаюсь написать все без сахара :-) Если сил хватит хочу тупо написать все что интересует сам...

Comment: Я согласен с автором вопроса. Иногда надо пощупать самому. Полезно для понимания.

Comment: Автору: вы напишите переворот без дополнительной памяти. Это будет полезнее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy прошу прощения за мою тупость, я слегка не понял это: temp = [None] * len(x) можно подробнее ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "вы напишите переворот без дополнительной памяти. Это будет полезнее." Я уже начал думать об этом... но похожу сложнее. Надеюсь пойму как это написать.

Comment: `[None] * 4` -> `[None, None, None, None]`.

Comment: Кстати, по-моему, массив можно перевернуть _гораздо_ проще: `x[::-1]`. Зачем расписывать на триста строк то, что можно сделать в одну?

Comment: @Глеб срезы аппэнды все эти сладости у меня на последок ;-) Хочу все сам с нуля :)

Comment: @GraceAI, как хотите) Я лично, когда питон изучал, сначала всю базовую теорию изучил, а потом уже задачи решал)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не "не разрешает индексировать пустой список" (именно так это называется в питоне), а "не позволяет обратиться к несуществующему элементу списка". И это логично и понятно. Если разрешить такое, то получится, что можно обратиться к, например, десятому элементу в списке из пяти элементов. Что вы хотели бы получить в этом случае?

Можете решить свою задачу без инициализации временного списка используя функцию `.append(x)`.  Она присоединяет `x` к концу списка.

Comment: Смысле ? Как это я буду обращаться к 10 индексу зная того что у меня список из 5 элементов ?

Comment: Точно так же, как вы хотите обратиться к какому-то индексу пустого списка, зная, что он пустой.

Comment: Так, я (у себя думаю :-D) что мм, не обращаюсь к индексу пустого списка, а пытаюсь создать индекс, я правильно думаю или нет ?

Comment: В JavaScript, например, массивы разреженные. Можно обратиться к десятому элементу пустого списка. Всё будет работать. То что Питон не растягивает список при обращении за конец - просто волевое решение.

Comment: Ну вот допустим вы попытаетесь создать индекс 10 в списке из 5 элементов. Что вы хотели бы получить в этом случае?

Comment: `a = []; a[10] = 1; a` -> `[ <10 empty items>, 1 ]`. Так в JS. :)

Comment: `a[5] = 2; a` -> `[ <5 empty items>, 2, <4 empty items>, 1 ]`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну так тут не яваскрипт :) И как по мне это ерунда какая-то получится - нельзя достоверно определить какие индексы есть, а каких нет.

Comment: В JS для проверки наличия индекса есть средства. Я только привел пример что политика "строгого регулирования размера в плотном массиве" не единственная возможная в скриптовых языках.

Comment: А зачем мне 10 индекс-то ? допустим как вы сказали у меня список из 5 элементов, если я хочу что то добавить добавлю после 5-го... а зачем думать о "дырке" если можно обойти дырку... Если хочу список из 5 элементов сделаю 5 элементов, если хочу 10 то 10 сделаю...

Comment: Я просто не хочу лишний цикл писать чтобы временным списком смог воспользоваться...

Comment: @GraceAI на вопрос "а зачем мне 10 индекс" я могу только ответить "а зачем вам индексация пустого списка" :) Мало ли зачем. Незачем, допустим, просто ошибка в коде. А сделать список из любого количества элементов можно и без цикла. В комментариях уже написали как.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а что будет, если обратиться к несуществующему индексу не для присвоения, а для чтения?

Comment: Хорошо я понял вас. Спасибо за советы и за ответы! ;-)

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю почему вы думаете об этих не существующих промежутках...

Comment: Как мы можем думать о том которого не существует то ? Размер списка точен, знаю что размер из 5 ти элементов, почему же я должен присваивать/читать из не существующего индекса знаю что такой индекс нет?

Comment: @GraceAI вопрос был для Stanislav Volodarskiy про яваскрипт :) А на свой вопрос " *почему же я должен присваивать/читать из не существующего индекса знаю что такой индекс нет?* " вы можете ответить и самостоятельно, ведь именно это и побудило создать вас эту тему - присваивание значения несуществующему индексу, зная, что такого индекса нет. Ну то есть вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему индексу и тут же задаете вопрос зачем вам это может потребоваться :)

Comment: Если обратится к несуществующему индексу будет возвращен `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Разреженные массивы в питоновских библиотеках есть, но в довольно продвинутых. В "научной" библиотеке `SciPy` есть раздел `scipy.sparse`, там разреженные матрицы живут. Нужно это обычно для совсем уж больших данных, когда экономия памяти при использовании разреженных данных будет критичной для работы программы (если без использования разреженных коллекций памяти для работы программы просто не хватит и она просто упадёт). Хотя разреженные матрицы всё-равно требуют при инициализации указать максимальный возможный размер матрицы. Просто при этом не происходит инициализации матрицы значениями и место на хранение не существующих элементов не тратится.

Для небольших же данных не сложно будет использовать питоновские быстрые инициализации для создания списка нужного размера, например:

```py
# заполняем нулями
temp = [0] * len(x)

# заполняем последовательно цифрами 0, 1, 2...
# это более короткий аналог вашего кода
temp = list(range(len(x)))

# делаем копию x
temp = x.copy()
# или так
temp = x[:]
```

Comment: `numpy.empty`...

Comment: @strawdog А, да. Как вариант инициализации произвольными значениями.